# Drupal 6 Webform - Component rendered in wrong position

Tags: 6, webforms

I'm adding a new component to a Drupal 6 webform. New 'select options' components are all rendered in the same area, no matter which position they are given in the backend. I've just added 'Area of Interest' as a listbox and as the first item of the webform. Check out where it ends up: http://enobia.cbstage.com/hcp/request-hypophosphatasia-information

The site was set up by another development team so I'm not sure what the heck they did to Webform. Anyone know what they could have done? I'm going to have to recreate the webform from scratch otherwise.

Pic of my setup screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq11q.png

Comment: The code shows that some fields are somehow subsets of others: webform-component-area-of-interest is inside webform-component-city; webform-component-country is inside webform-selects (?). Can you upload a screenshot of the webform fields config page?

Comment: Added a picture - let me know if you want to see anything else. I'm going to replace Webform with a fresh copy and see what happens.

Comment: The setup doesn't explain the odd nesting. Hopefully your clean install will work.

Comment: Found the problem - it was in a javascript file I had thought was a jQuery plugin. Easy enough to fix. Thanks for your help!